# shell script create variable and find variable in file

Tags: linux, shell, awk, getline

I have data that looks like this:

```
M-089]action=;Params=0000000;
M-091]act=;Params=3333333;
M-091]2001
M-090]action=;Params=3333333;
M-090]2001
M-089]4241
```

Find "action=" string and use Method number same number. Example 089 or 090

```
M-089]action=;Params=0000000;M-089]4241
M-090]action=;Params=3333333;M-090]2001


nawk '/action=/' | sed 's/]//'| awk '{val=$1;getline $1;print val,$1}' infile
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: nawk needs the infile, not awk.

Comment: @jww : Calling this off-topic seems a bit to harsh for me. It might well be that the command which the OP put for discussion, is part of a shell **script**, in which case the question indeed is about programming. Especially in the context of shell commands, I find it sometimes not obvious where it is best to post a question. Note also that, while it is indeed unclear what the OP wanted to know, at least the title of the post includes the words *shell script*.

Comment: @MaisSharifli : I don't see a question in your post. What is it that you actually want to ask? And I think you should remove the *getline* tag, as it doesn't seem related to your post. See [the definition of the getline tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getline).

Comment: #not sure what is the question:
would you like a way to concatenate lines    that follow - Find "action=" stirng and use Method number same number. Example 089 or 090 ?

Comment: @user1934428 - *"It might well be that the command which the OP put for discussion, is part of a shell script, in which case the question indeed is about programming..."* - I believe the bar is higher than adding "... in a script" to a question. If the problem is reduced to a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (which it appears so), then it is just a question on how to run a Unix text processing command. There are better sites to ask those types of questions.

Answer (score 0):

## Answer:

Assuming you just want to **concatenate lines that have the same Method number**
This is a solution for you: **output is not in the same order of the original file**

```
sort -r infile | awk -F "]" '{printf NR%2?$0:$0"\n"}' | awk /action/
```

1) `sort -r infile` - get related lines above each other (`M-090]action comes be for M-090]`**`Number`** in the **ascii table**)

2) split line with `"]"`

3) data is sorted , it is easy check if line is even print `$0` else print $0 and new line (`$0"\n"`)

4) result is filtered for lines with your string `awk /action/`